# Command substitution in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to read the first six characters of a text file into a string and prepend every other non-blank line in that file with that string. An example of such file could be:

```
04/17 Walmart .toys $ 70 .cash $ -70

Caltex .gas 20 $ .cheque $ -20

McDonalds .burger 1 $ .cash $ -1
```

Each entry, i.e.: each non-empty line, needs a date, which for reasons of easy data entry has been entered on the first line only. Entries are separated by 1 or more empty lines. The output would look like this:

```
04/17 Walmart .toys $ 70 .cash $ -70

04/17 Caltex .gas 20 $ .cheque $ -20

04/17 McDonalds .burger 1 $ .cash $ -1
```

I can match the non empty strings with things like [^[^@]+[ ]*.*[ ]*([^;{}:]+)[ ]*$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315675/match-newlines-in-non-empty-lines-and-not-preceded-by-some-characters), but I don't know how to actually implement that for non blank lines.

[This Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785564/checking-for-empty-lines-in-a-file/20789484#20789484) looks attractive to me, but I don't know how then to insert my string at the start.

I also can't find the straight answer to my question on Stack Overflow.

I tried a script which accepts a file name:

```
read -n 6 date < $1
sed 's/^/$(echo $date)/' | \
sed 's/^$(echo $date)\n//' | > $newName
```

I was able to come up with prepending the date with space (e.g. the string: '04/17 ') to every line, and then remove the same from every line in which nothing follows.

However, it seems that sed doesn't accept the command substitution:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with one `sed` command:

```
read -rn 6 date < "$1"
sed -E 's#^([a-zA-Z]+)#'"$date"' \1#g' "$1" > newfile
```

The capture group ensures there's at least one character on the line before inserting the date.

**EDIT**: Based on the revision to your question:

```
newfile="output.txt"
lineone=$(head -1 "$1");

read -rn 6 date <<< "$lineone"
sed -E 's#^([a-zA-Z]+)#'"$date"' \1#g; 1s#^.*$#'"$lineone"'#' "$1" > "$newfile"
```

Since you aren't doing an in-place edit, you can do the $date insertions, and then go back and swap out the first line since it would end up with two dates. There might be "better" ways to do this such as using `Perl`, or losing the second `sed` command, although this should at least give you a basic idea though on how it works...

**Result** (newfile):

```
04/17 Walmart .toys $ 70 .cash $ -70

04/17 Caltex .gas 20 $ .cheque $ -20

04/17 McDonalds .burger 1 $ .cash $ -1
```

> NOTE: In some versions of `sed` the option for extended regex can
>   either be `-r` or `-E`.

Comment: This is strange, it doesn't seem to do anything here, except hanging in my GNU sed 4.2.1. But I think I see more or less what you're trying to do.

Comment: The manpage of GNU sed 4.2.1 doesn't mention the '-E' option. I tried the '-r' option, but still hanging.

Comment: Hah, I tried your solution with the `while read` loop and it works after some minor edits. This newest, and also working solution of yours is I think most elegant so I'll go with that. -r works indeed instead of -E, funny thing is that GNU sed 4.2.1 doesn't protest against using -E. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! I presumed you might need to tweak a few things perhaps, but at least you should have plenty to work with now — cheers! :)

Answer (score 3):

Pure `bash` answer:

```
unset n
while read -r x ; do
    case "${#n}$x" in 6) ;; 6*) x="$n$x" ;; *) n="${x:0:6}" ;; esac
    echo "$x"
done < file > newfile
```

Output:

```
04/17 Walmart .toys $ 70 .cash $ -70

04/17 Caltex .gas 20 $ .cheque $ -20

04/17 McDonalds .burger 1 $ .cash $ -1
```

Comment: I didn't test it because I already went with I'L'I's solution, but it looks good indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl:

```
perl -plE 'if($.==1){$d=substr($_,0,6);next}elsif(/./){s/^/$d/}' file > new
```

Output

```
04/17 Walmart .toys $ 70 .cash $ -70

04/17 Caltex .gas 20 $ .cheque $ -20

04/17 McDonalds .burger 1 $ .cash $ -1
```

Or in same file with backup to `file.bak`

```
perl -i.bak -plE 'if($.==1){$d=substr($_,0,6);next}elsif(/./){s/^/$d/}' file
```

Or same file *without* backup

```
perl -i -plE 'if($.==1){$d=substr($_,0,6);next}elsif(/./){s/^/$d/}' file
```

Or, if you're unsure about the leading zeros in the date,

```
perl -plE 'if($.==1){($d)=m|^(\d+/\d+\s)|;next}elsif(/./){s/^/$d/}' file
```

will match any `digit(s) / digit(s) space` on the beginning of the 1st line.

As  [l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll) mentioned in comment, the above adds the date to pseudo-empty lines too (where the line only looks-like empty) e.g. it contains at least one space. In such case, instead of `/./`:

- Use `/\w/` - so, prepend the date only to lines containing at least one word character;
- Or use `/\S/` - when containing at least one non-space character

Explanation:

```
perl -plE '                    # Run the commands on every input line and print them.
    if( $. == 1) {             # If it is the 1st line
        $d = substr($_, 0, 6); # take the first 6 characters and store it to $d
        next                   # And continue to the next line.
    }
    elsif( /\S/ ) {            # Else if the line contains any nonspace character
        s/^/$d/                # add to the beginning the content of $d
    }
    ' file > new
```

Comment: Very nice answer, you got my vote :) — there's only one issue though I might mention. If the blank line starts with a space then you'll end up with a date on it.

Comment: @l'L'l - yes, probably instead of `/./` is better to use `/\w/`. Thanx. :)

Comment: Yeah I had to change mine also, great answer regardless.

Comment: Looks good indeed, only... I don't 'speak' perl and that's why I went with I'L'I's answer. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @HarryH of course that's ok. :) The answer remains here for other users with similar problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

The slash is terminating the sed command, change the delimiter to something else:

```
"s#^#$(echo $date)#"
```

You could probably write like this too:

```
"s#^#$date#"
```

Note however that this approach is generally fragile (as you have discovered), because you can't treat the variable as a literal string.

---

Based on the samples on the updated question, I would suggest to use a single awk command to do your text processing. Something like this could give you the sample output:

```
$ cat file
04/17 Walmart .toys $ 70 .cash $ -70

Caltex .gas 20 $ .cheque $ -20

McDonalds .burger 1 $ .cash $ -1

$ awk 'NR==1{d=$1}NR>1&&NF>0{$0=d" "$0}1' file
04/17 Walmart .toys $ 70 .cash $ -70

04/17 Caltex .gas 20 $ .cheque $ -20

04/17 McDonalds .burger 1 $ .cash $ -1
```

Comment: You're right on both counts. Thanks a lot! However, `read -n 6 date < $1` omits the 6th character, i.e.: the space, so I've had to add it manually. No problem though. Then there is the problem that `"s#^$date#\n#"` doesn't do what I wanted it to do: replace the lines with only a date (and space) with an empty line, which is understandable. Any idea how to obtain that effect?

Comment: @HarryH: I am not sure I understand the requirement... Could you update the question to include sample input data and the expected output for that data?

Comment: I just added input and expected output samples.

Comment: @HarryH: I see you already accepted an answer, but I added another alternative with `awk`, that is preferable in my opinion for reasons of efficiency and clarity of code. For example the accepted answer will fail if the first field of the first line of the file contains a hash character `#`.

Comment: That is a very nice short code! Sorry that I already selected the answer, which is also working for me and uses sed, which I understand a bit, contrary  to awk. But you solution is really nice looking.

Comment: This would fail for "05 17 name"

Comment: @ctfd: So? It's not OP's date format... Just change `d=$1` with `d=substr($0,1,6)` if you want to use the first six characters.

Comment: @ctfd: The fixed format for the 1st 6 characters is "mm/dd ", so it's not a problem.